# convert Swedish letter to english string in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to convert

```
@"V&#228;sterg&#246;k&#32;&#38;&#32;&#214;sterg&#246;k"
```

string into english string in iPhone.but no luck till now.

I have tried

```
    const char *cc = [d cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:cc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Download [this project](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser).
Copy these files in your project 
`NSString+HTML.h` 
`NSString+HTML.m` 
`GTMNSString+HTML.h` 
`GTMNSString+HTML.m`

`#import "NSString+HTML.h"` in your file where you want to decode your html string.

Use code as

```
NSString *htmlStr = @"V&#228;sterg&#246;k&#32;&#38;&#32;&#214;sterg&#246;k" ;
NSString *notmarStr = [htmlStr stringByDecodingHTMLEntities];
NSLog(@"%@",notmarStr);
```

`Output:Västergök & Östergök`